# Checking $g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}f(x-r_n)\in L_1$ for $r_i\in\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $x^{-1/2}$ for $0<x<1$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. Let $(r_n)$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$ and let $g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}f(x-r_n)$. Show that $g\in L_1$ and in particular, $g$ is finite a.e.

With the help of Greg, I think I have an idea. If I have that $f(x)=0$ when I take the integral term by term of the sum, it is certainly finite. On the other hand at worst case scenario I will have $x$ close to $0$ being raised to a high power so this will give me a very small number but since it is in the denominator it will give me something approaching infinity.

I know that $f$ is integrable and $f^2$ is not integrable. So maybe I could say something along the lines of $g$ is integrable because it is the sum of integrable functions?

Comment: There are many things you need to prove. Are you saying you have no idea how to start thinking about any of them? Do you know the definition of $L_1$? If you wanted to integrate $g(x)$, which is defined by a sum, over all of $\Bbb R$, what would be the first logical thing to try?

Comment: $L_1$ is the space of Lebesgue integrable functinos

Comment: I guess I could integrate $g(x)$ term by term.

Comment: I know that the rationals have measure zero, so that might have something to do with showing that $g$ is finite a.e perhaps.

Comment: Good, so what happens when you integrate term by term?

Comment: I get $\int g(x)=\frac{1}{2}\int f(x-r_1)+\frac{1}{4}\int f(x-r_2)+\ldots$., but I'm not sure whether $x-r_1$ is in between $0$ and $1$ or not, so I can't use the information given in the exercise about the values of $f$

Comment: Ok: but the integral is over all real numbers $x$, so probably some of the time those differences $x-r_n$ are going to be between $0$ and $1$. Maybe a change of variables inside each integral will help?